# Can I move the Submit button on the entry screen to the top of the window?

Tags: control-panel

I've got clients who have a problem remembering to scroll down to the bottom of long entry screens to click the "submit" button on a regular entry screen.

I was thinking it would be good if I could either move the one on the bottom up to the top, or better yet, have a duplicate "submit" button at the top.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't answer in details right now but look up (google) ExpressionEngine Accessory development. An EE accessory would let you insert JavaScript on control panel pages, such as using jQuery to insert a `<button>` element near the top of the entry form, and hooking it to trigger a entry form submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an Extension rather than Accessory. There are already ones out there that will do the job, or you can tweak slightly. The one I use the most is [Publish Bar](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publish-bar).

Other options...

[Control Panel CSS/JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) - create your own by injecting JS/CSS on that page.

[Publish Tweeks](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publish-tweeks) - might do it can't recall (been a while since I used it)

[Chilli: Save for Publisher](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/chilli-save-for-publisher) - Does the job if you're using Publisher add-on

Comment: Thanks, [Publish Bar](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publish-bar) was the answer for me for this case. Something to note: when I was first searching for a solution, I found Pub Bar, but the description said it just creates a button that's sticky to the bottom; it's only in the support area that it's mentioned that in the latest version it also creates a button on the top.