# Create a second save button on top of entry page in EE3?

Tags: control-panel, ee3

This [answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/can-i-move-the-submit-button-on-the-entry-screen-to-the-top-of-the-window) does almost have what I need.

But it's two years old and nothing in the links provided in the answer points to a solution for EE3.

I want another <kbd>save</kbd> / <kbd>save + close</kbd> button pair on top of the entry as I am editing very long entries with many fields.

**Does anybody have a working solution for EE3?**

Can I use i.e. the plugin [Publish Bar](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publish-bar) which has been last updated in 2011? Did the EE plugin API change a lot since then?

I don't want to alter the backend code, as that would be a lot of work for each time I need to update EE3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is very easy. You just need to call jQuery on a `cp_js_end` hook. Just copy and paste the code below.

Instructions:

1. Access your EE install via FTP and go to the folder system/user/addons
2. Create a folder inside **addons** folder and name it `button_move`
3. Create a file inside it named `addon.setup.php` and paste this code inside it:

   ```
   <?php
   return array(
       'author' => 'Mufi',
       'author_url' => '#',
       'description' => 'Copy Channel entry submit button to TOP',
       'docs_url' => '#',
       'name' => 'Clone Channel entry Button to TOP',
       'settings_exist' => false,
       'version' => '1.0.0',
       'namespace'   => 'EllisLab\Addons\Button_move',
   );
   ```
4. Create a file named `ext.button_move.php` and paste this code inside:

   ```
   <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die('No direct script access allowed');
   class Button_move_ext
   {
       public $version         = "1.0.0";
       public $name            = 'Clone Channel entry Button to TOP';
       public $description     = 'Copy Channel entry submit button to TOP';
       public $docs_url        = '#';
       public $settings_exist  = FALSE;
       public $settings        = array();
       public $hook            = 'cp_js_end';

       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->EE =& get_instance();
           $this->site_id = $this->EE->config->item('site_id');

       }

       public function activate_extension()
       {
            $data = array( 'class'     =>  __CLASS__,
                           'method'    =>  "copy_btn",
                           'hook'      =>  $this->hook,
                           'settings'  =>  "",
                           'priority'  =>  100,
                           'version'   =>  $this->version,
                           'enabled'   =>  'y'
           );
           // insert in database
           $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);
       }

       public function disable_extension()
       {
           $this->EE->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
           $this->EE->db->delete('extensions');
       }

       public function update_extension($current=FALSE)
       {
           if($current == $this->version) return false;

           // Update the extension
           $this->EE->db
               ->where('class', __CLASS__)
               ->update('extensions', array('version' => $this->version));
       }

       public function copy_btn()
       {

           $js = '';
           if ($this->EE->extensions->last_call !== FALSE)
           {
               $js = $this->EE->extensions->last_call;
           }

           $js .= "var url = document.URL;
                   var chk = url.search('/cp/publish/edit/entry');
                   if(url.search('/cp/publish/edit/entry') != -1 || (url.search('/cp/publish/create') != -1))
                   {
                       $(document).ready(function(){
                           $('ul.tabs').next('form').prepend($('ul.tabs').next('form').find('fieldset.form-ctrls').clone().removeClass('form-ctrls').addClass('top-btn').css('margin-bottom', '10px').css('text-align', 'center'));
                       });
                   }";
           return $js;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
5. In Add-on Manager inside the CP  install the plugin called **Clone Channel entry Button to TOP**.

All the publish entry/edit entry pages now have a button at the top as well as the original one at the bottom.